# Good console / debugging software for javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, debugging, console

I was searching for software that would help me with JavaScript development (I'm a beginner).
I learned most of what I know from [Codecademy](http://codecademy.com) where they have nifty and very use-full console, I was looking for something similar but that it would be possible to install on my mac (or accessible online).

I guess main usage of such software should be ability to return, print etc.. things of javascript and show error messages to help with debugging purposes. If you have any good suggestions please share it.

Comment: All of this is available in your browser : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Chrome Console (built in, look for Developer Tools in the menu) and Firefox's Firebug are both the preeminent Javascript debug and developer toolkits. Right-click and Inspect element, there you go. There's also Venkmen and some others. Fiddler I think also helps. http://jsfiddle.net also let's you do handy code practice/development in a handy direct input interface. Just look around.

Comment: I use the Firefox Firebug addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which is a code quality analysis tool that helps check any errors or styling issues you may have. You don't have to make all the nit-picky changes it talks about (and you can filter some things) but it definitely helps out. Just post your Javascript there.

I would also consider putting `use strict;` at the top of your Javascript because it helps throw more errors which can be useful when starting out. Here's an SO question about it:

[What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

As other people have said, Firebug is a great extension for Firefox and Chrome I think the standard console embedded in the browser is sufficient.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It might be funny, but I always use chrome console and firebug for such testing cases. i think you won't find anything faster.

As for a software try [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/download) it is very user friendly.